# How do I create an AutoCommandBufferBuilder in vulkano-rs "0.23.0"?

Tags: rust, gpu, vulkan

I am following along the examples in the `vulkano-rs` website and at the section where it says to create an `AutoCommandBufferBuilder`, it says to use `AutoCommandBufferBuilder::new()` to create it.

However, in the latest version of `vulkano-rs` - `0.23.0` - this method is missing.

If I downgrade to version `0.22.0`, the method exists.

So, how do I create an `AutoCommandBuffer` in the latest version of `vulkano-rs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [vulkano-rs/vulkano#1527](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/issues/1527):

> `AutoCommandBufferBuilder::new` renamed to `AutoCommandBufferBuilder::primary/secondary`. For `primary` form there is a new additional 3rd parameter. Use `CommandBufferUsage::MultipleSubmit` for this parameter to fulfill the same behavior you previously had with old `new` constructor.